# page curl effect landscape mode one page only

Tags: android

I am using code from [this](https://github.com/harism/android_page_curl/) site to implement the page curl effect in my app. As I am working in landscape mode, it automatically shows two pages side by side. I don't want that. I want to show a single page in the landscape mode like the one shown in the portrait mode. How can I achieve it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the repository log and you will find that all pages will be 2-sided since the [commit](https://github.com/harism/android_page_curl/commit/ef554ee84cb433c1ff2ebad194424ff3cb3c62f8) in May 06, 2012.

Cags12 added the 2 page support in his [commit](https://github.com/harism/android_page_curl/commit/cc7be02e68137ab21843531d600a53ae7d33d29a) in Apr 30, 2012 and in his code there is a legacy option to disable the 2 pages in CurlActivity.java

```
// CAGS: This is to allow 2 pages landscape mode, set to false for legacy mode
 mCurlView.set2PagesLandscape(true);
```

This however is not in the master branch, but maybe you can use the commit from the [merge](https://github.com/harism/android_page_curl/commit/0f489edec647dbe59f7fd35abe97af96c658073f), altough it might be missing some fixes made afterwards. Check the comments on why it was removed at the end of [this](https://github.com/harism/android_page_curl/commit/ef554ee84cb433c1ff2ebad194424ff3cb3c62f8) commit.

Comment: Thanks Mikel! Exactly what I wanted!

Comment: Do you know why the pages are not displayed in order?

Comment: No idea... Check [this](https://github.com/harism/android_page_curl/issues/17), issue might be related. Also check the rest of the issues, might find something you could need.